# Child build.gradle not evaluating at afterEvaluate event

Tags: gradle

I have a project with 21 subprojects. one of those subprojects has its own build.gradle file because its a little obscure.

Now, i have a configuration setting in the build that is needed during the config phase. So, in my plugin i have

```
project.afterEvaluate {
  if (project == project.rootProject) {
        project.allprojects.each { proj ->
      MetaExtension config = proj.getExtensions().getByType(MetaExtension)
      if (config.inventoryHash == null){
        throw new ProjectHashNotSetException(proj.name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if i have everything in one build.gradle file, it all works perfectly. but, as soon as i broke the 21st subproject into its own build.gradle file, it now always comes back as null. copy and past back into one build.gradle file, works fine, 2 gradle files, fails.

Why would this be?

Comment: What is the content of the build.gradle file for the 21st subproject? The same as quoted here? Also, you mention a plugin. Are you writing a plugin?

Comment: LOL, the project is a series of plugins.  this is the small one.  the contents of the file for the 21st build.gradle is a custom dependency compiler for a language some brain surgeons decided to invent a few years ago at my company.

Comment: does the root project know about the subproject then? what is in your `settings.gradle?`

Answer (score 0):

`afterEvaluate` is a method of the project and is evaluated after the project is evaluated, not after all projects are evaluated.

You need to restructure your logic. You could e. g. add an `evaluationDependsOnChildren()` or `evaluationDependsOn '21st-project'`, then you don't need the `afterEvaluate` at all.

Actually if the shown code is your actual code, it is a bit strange anyway. You add an `afterEvaluate` action to all projects, but only execute it if it is the root project. You could as well just add the action to the root project and then leave out the condition. Or maybe even better, just add an afterEvaluate to each project that checks exactly that project like

```
project.afterEvaluate {
  MetaExtension config = extensions.getByType(MetaExtension)
  if (!config.inventoryHash) {
    throw new ProjectHashNotSetException(name)
  }
}
```

Then the evaluation order is not important, as each is checked individually. This is also better for project decoupling if you e. g. ever want to use configure-on-demand which would not be possible with your approach.